# How can I achieve this search condition?

Tags: asp.net

I want to implement some search condition like the below which I want to make in best optimized way, how can I achieve this?

```
switch (e.CommandName)
{
   case "DRESS":
      chkItem.Items.Clear();
      chkItem.DataSource = cDressing.GetAllDressingDetail(cWebUtil.CurrClientID);
      chkItem.DataTextField = "Description";
      chkItem.DataValueField = "DressingID";
      chkItem.DataBind();
      CurrBtnMode = btnMode.Dressing;
      // ModalPopupExtender1.TargetControlID = ((Button)grdOrder.Rows[currItem.OrderItemID -1].FindControl("btnDress")).ID.ToString();

      if (currItem.DressingItems.Count > 0)
      {
         foreach(cOrderItemDressing itemDress in currItem.DressingItems )
         {
            // I want here to apply condtion for those chkItem object's DressingID exist in the itemDress objets's  DressingID should 
            // have checked state in checkbox list to be populated.
         }
      }

      ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
```

Comment: can i use some lambda expression for this..

Comment: in fact i am unable to make it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is you goal to check the items in the `chkItem.Items` that have a matching item in the `currItem.DressingItems` collection? I'm not sure if this is what you want to get, but you can try this:

```
...
//uncheck all the items first (if you need it)
foreach (var item in chkItem.Items)
{
    item.Checked = false;   
}

foreach(cOrderItemDressing itemDress in currItem.DressingItems )
{

    bool chkItemFound = false;
    foreach (var item in chkItem.Items)
    {
        //if the item is found, make it checked
        if (item.DressingID == itemDress.DressingID)
        {
            item.Checked = true;
            chkItemFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this yet, so if you've got some issues when using it, just let me know.

**Update**

You asked if it's the most optimized way of solving the issue. I would say there are more optimized methods, but I wanted to keep the code simple to just show the solution.
It may be sufficient, but it depends on how many items does each of the collections contain.

I suppose that a quite simple way to optimize it would be preventing so many items comparisons by removing an item you've already found (because it's not needed in further comparisons). This way the collection can shrink with each loop iteration, making it work faster. You may need, however, to create a copy of the collection you want to modify in order to have acces to its original form (and keep note that allocation of this array can take some time).
Another way would be using sorted collections and implementing some kind of searching algorithm for them. This will make the searching process itself faster, but needs some additional time to sort the collections (sorting can also be implemented by creating collection in a sorted form, so no sorting is needed later).

There are probably some other ways to do it, but it can depend on the details of other parts of your application and amount of data you want it to work with.

Comment: It works but is it the most optimized way of doing it, or other solutions exist?

Comment: I've updated the answer with some information about possible optimizations.